# ElasticSearch MapperParsingExceptionn with geo_distance filter

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

I'm using the [`grails elasticsearch`](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) plugin in my application, and I am running across an odd exception.

I have a method that builds a request using a `geo_distance` filter that way:

```java
def activityList = ElasticSearchService.search(
            [types:[DomainA, DomainB],
            sort: orderBy, order: orderAs, size: (int)maxRes],
                {
                    // bla bla bla some working closure building a working query

                    }

                    if(centerLat != -1){
                        filter{
                            geo_distance(
                                'distance': searchRadius,
                                'activityLocation': [lat: (Double)centerLat, lon: (Double)centerLon]
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
```

And whenever I try to use the method with the filter (that is, when I set for example `searchRadius` to `'5km'` and `centerLat`/ `centerLon` to correct coordinates, my `ElasticSearch` node goes crazy and keeps logging the following error until I shut it down:

```shell
| Error 2014-08-27 10:31:49,076 [elasticsearch[Agent Zero][bulk][T#2]] ERROR index.IndexRequestQueue  - Failed bulk item: MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[field must be either 'lat', 'lon' or 'geohash'];
```

I tried looking around the web for the reason why this `MappingParserException` is thrown, and I ended up looking at the [source code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoUtils.java) for the `org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoUtils` class. Apparenty, the exception is thrown because my `lat` and `lon` fields are not numbers (see lines `372` and `381`).

**Why is this happening? Did I declare my filter wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and this problem made me lose my nerves quite a bit, but I have finally solved it.

I was mapping the following classes that way:

```
class A{

static searchable={
    activityLocation geoPoint:true, component:true
    // some other mappings on some other fields
}

Location activityLocation

// some other fields

}
a
class Location{
    static searchable = true

    String locationName

    Double lat

    Double lon
}
```

There were two problems:

1. I didn't want to use the `root false` option when mapping my `activityLocation` objects, because I wanted to be able to search them directly, which caused my `A` objects to contain the following property (note the presence of the `id` field):

   `'activityLocation' : { 'id':'1', 'locationName' : 'foo', 'lat': '42.5464', 'lon': '65.5647' }`

which isn't a `geoPoint` because it has more than just a `lat` and `lon` field.

2. I was mapping the `locationName` property as part of my `activityLocation` objects, which makes them **not** `geoPoint`s.

I ended up solving the problem by changing the mapping to the following values for `activityLocation`:

```
ActivityLocation{
    static searchable = {
        only = ['lat', 'lon']
        root false
    }

    String locationName

    Double lat

    Double lon
}
```

This solved my problem and my search went well from then on.

I have to add that I was pretty confused by the docs regarding this and I am a bit disappointed that I can't map a `geoPoint` with more attributes. I wish it were possible to have other fields in the mapping.

Furthermore, I wish the plugin gave me better access to the ES logs, it took me a while to figure out where to look for the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem is with your index types mapping, in order to understand what is the problem you have to post some example of the data you are indexing and type mappings (you can get your current mappings from host:port/{index}/_mapping/{type}).
Try to define the mapping as explained here: http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/mapping.html look at 3.3.2 GeoPoint, make sure you define your data points correctly.

Comment: I actually found out what was going on, I'll post a detailed answer as I think the docs aren't very clear.

Comment: As it turns out, it was indeed a mapping problem, but the docs state that *'The field for the longitude has to be named lon and the field for the latitude has to be named lat'*, not that **there cannot be any other fields**. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mapping for activityLocation is "geo_point" then you shouldn't need to preface your coordindate with "lat" and "lon" and should just be able to send

```
'activityLocation': [(Double)centerLat,(Double)centerLon]
```

I think this "lat" "lon" preface might have been supported as a geo_point format in earlier versions, but as of 1.0.0 I don't think it still is.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have managed to fix this with few lines of coded added to "DeepDomainClassMarshaller.groovy" and overriding this file. 

Previous code:-
if (DomainClassArtefactHandler.isDomainClass(propertyClass)) {
                String searchablePropertyName = getSearchablePropertyName()
                if (propertyValue.class."$searchablePropertyName") {
                    // todo fixme - will throw exception when no searchable field.
                    marshallingContext.lastParentPropertyName = prop.name
                    marshallResult += [(prop.name): ([id: propertyValue.ident(), 'class': propertyClassName] + marshallingContext.delegateMarshalling(propertyValue, propertyMapping.maxDepth))]
                } else {
                    marshallResult += [(prop.name): [id: propertyValue.ident(), 'class': propertyClassName]]
                }

                // Non-domain marshalling
            }

New Code:-
if (DomainClassArtefactHandler.isDomainClass(propertyClass)) {
                String searchablePropertyName = getSearchablePropertyName()
                if (propertyValue.class."$searchablePropertyName") {
                    // todo fixme - will throw exception when no searchable field.
                    marshallingContext.lastParentPropertyName = prop.name
                    if(propertyMapping?.isGeoPoint())
                        marshallResult += [(prop.name): (marshallingContext.delegateMarshalling(propertyValue, propertyMapping.maxDepth))]
                    else
                        marshallResult += [(prop.name): ([id: propertyValue.ident(), 'class': propertyClassName] + marshallingContext.delegateMarshalling(propertyValue, propertyMapping.maxDepth))]
                } else {
                    marshallResult += [(prop.name): [id: propertyValue.ident(), 'class': propertyClassName]]
                }

                // Non-domain marshalling
            }

Let me know in case issue still persists.

Note:- I am still using elasticsearch:0.0.3.3.
```